# why is my line break not working in vue? probably something wrong with flex?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, frontend, stylus

I wanted to have a line break and in tried using <span> & <br>, and tried

[image: code]

however, the line break did not work:

[image: browser]

---

I will post the related css code below (I used flex and that is probably the issues as I described previously in the question, but I mean, I have to write some more words according to the system):

```css
.modal-mask {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9998;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    display: table;
    transition: opacity .3s ease;
}

.modal-wrapper {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.modal-container {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .33);
    transition: all .3s ease;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.modal-header h3 {
    margin-top: 0;
    color: #42b983;
}

.flex
    display flex
    justify-content center

.close
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border none
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 10px 20px;

    &:hover
        background:rgba(0,0,0,0.20)

.modal-body {
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.modal-enter {
    opacity: 0;
}

.modal-leave-active {
    opacity: 0;
}

.modal-enter .modal-container,
.modal-leave-active .modal-container {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

I basically went:

```html
    <model v-model="info">
      <div><b>ls / ll: </b>list files</div>
      <div><b>cat: </b>print file content</div>
    </model>
```

and thanks to the reminder of @evolutionbox

```html
    <model v-model="info">
      <span><b>ls / ll: </b>list files</span>
      <br />
      <span><b>cat: </b>print file content</span>
    </model>
```

Comment: Please do not include code in screenshots. I can't see the usage of `<br>` inside `<span>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your model has a property display: flex. Try to add flex-direction: column; It will stack elements below each other.

```
display: flex
flex-direction: column;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code snipped uses a `<b>` tag instead of `<br />`.

Comment: nah it was because it want things to be in bold